# Placing two (or more) multi-line variables next to each other bash

Tags: bash, formatting

Lets say I have 3 variables, each with a multi-line output, like so:

```
IPs="10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.3
10.0.0.4"

MACs="08:16:E9:3D:12:D5
C6:70:A5:25:FF:58
42:96:ED:C8:D5:80
05:89:C6:37:68:9B"

Vendors="Apple
Intel
Sagemcom
HP"
```

and I want to put them next to each other, like so:

```
10.0.0.1 08:16:E9:3D:12:D5 Apple
10.0.0.2 C6:70:A5:25:FF:58 Intel
10.0.0.3 42:96:ED:C8:D5:80 Sagemcom
10.0.0.4 05:89:C6:37:68:9B HP
```

How would I do so?

Comment: What is your word separator, you don't have any delimiter between the words?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Just the \ does not add the new-line character after the word as you need it, for e.g. the variable will be printed as `JamesJulieJohnathonJess`, you can't split unless you have a de-limiter

Comment: This was an example, my actual variable in my script has newlines

Comment: Will there be always a mapping between each of those variables? meaning always equal number of entries?

Comment: It will be good if you can update with your attempts, you can attract more answers if you share your attempts even if they don't work

Comment: Yes there will be an equal number of scenarios. I am using NMap, which scans for IP addresses, MAC addresses and does a reverse lookup on those MAC addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With paste and bash:

```
paste -d " " <(echo "$IPs") <(echo "$MACs") <(echo "$Vendors")
```

```
10.0.0.1 08:16:E9:3D:12:D5 Apple
10.0.0.2 C6:70:A5:25:FF:58 Intel
10.0.0.3 42:96:ED:C8:D5:80 Sagemcom
10.0.0.4 05:89:C6:37:68:9B HP
```

Answer (score 0):

We on macOS (BSD) also:

```
rs 3 <<<"$IPs $MACs $Vendors" | rs -C' ' -T
```

```
10.0.0.1 08:16:E9:3D:12:D5 Apple 
10.0.0.2 C6:70:A5:25:FF:58 Intel 
10.0.0.3 42:96:ED:C8:D5:80 Sagemcom 
10.0.0.4 05:89:C6:37:68:9B HP
```